# Laravel 4 app logs user out anytime an AJAX POST is made

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-4

I have a nightmare of a Laravel 4 issue.

Anytime and every single time an AJAX POST is made to the server in the app, it immediately logs the user you of the system!  This is horrible and impossible to debug ti seems

Does anyone have any ideas for a solution?

Below are some examples of the AJAX request being made...

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/orders/orderboards/order/add-item-comment',
    data: 'order_item_id=' + order_item_id+'&name='+name+'&body='+body+'&user_id='+user_id,
    success: function(result) {
      if(result.success){
        console.log('SUCCESS AJAX Comment created: ');


        working = false;
        $(result.html).hide().insertBefore('#addCommentContainer').slideDown();
        $('#body').val('');

      }else{
        console.log('FAILURE AJAX did not save comment:');
      }

    }
});
```

I also use the jQuery library X-Editable on some fields of my app which turns fields into edit in place and it handles all the AJAX side of those posts as well.

I can use an AJAX request to load data without issue, it is just when a POST is made to create or update data that you are logged out.

---

### UPDATE

It seems anytime an AJAX request is made to server it is resetting the `laravel_session` cookie value.  I am not sure what would cause this.

I have noticed in the past if I turn on the config debugging option then each request also resets this value and logs you out.  It seems AJAX request also make this behavior happen =(

Any ideas for a solution?

Comment: Is it a 401 that you get back? How long does it takes for the request to finish?

Comment: Does the response contain any delete cookie headers?

Comment: Did you set up any sort of authentication filters that could be capturing the request and logging the user out?

Comment: @JSelser it is a 200 success page and then my next page request loads the login screen.  Looking at the cookie it appears the `laravel_session` clookie is set with a new session id.  I cannot figure out what is causing it though

Comment: @PatrickM I am not sure but it does appear that the laravel session id is being reset and this is the headers from the actual AJAX request in this screenshot http://i.imgur.com/tJ4CDNZ.png it does show a `set-cookie` part which could be what you mean?

Comment: @user3158900 The page does have basic filter to require user to be logged in but that is it.  It seems there session id is being reset when ajax request is made for some reason

Comment: Maybe this will help https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/8172

Comment: What session driver are you using? Have you tried using another one? Have you tried another environment?

Comment: Can you post your `routes` and `filters` ?

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with the AJAX POST or x-edit. I use them both on a Laravel 4 project. However, it seems that your session is not stored properly. It is either your cache or session setup. I had glitches when Cache, Session and Cookies in Laravel had embedded . : in the name. Everything would seem to work when saved but when the code tried to retrieve the value it would come back empty.

Comment: If you're using Laravel's inbuilt Auth method I would suggest simply adding a remember_token field to your user table. Laravel then automatically knows where to store the user's session token.

Answer (score 0):

This was a very super strange issue which I still do not know the reasoning for it however I do know the cause now...

My JavaScript app made an AJAX request to build the content of a Modal window.  In this generated HTML, it made a request to get a Gravatar image and when the image was not a correct URL to a real gravatar image, it forced my user to be instantly logged out of my Laravel 4 app.

I have no idea why that would do anything my my server.  Would love to hear some reasoning?

Comment: If you're using the `file` driver for sessions, there are race conditions when making multiple quick requests to the same app. Try a different session driver - database or Redis/memcached.