# Laravel 4 app resets laravel_session COOKIE every time an AJAX request is made

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-4

Laravel 4 app resets `laravel_session` COOKIE every time an AJAX request is made

When I load a page is might have this cookie set

```
laravel_session = 
eyJpdiI6IkJcL1VpcXM5eHRmZkZpMVp6OWw3UDRyV0FZazlGcTA2Y01VYWdHd1wvbndHdz0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6ImRuOFZsUnhBTnZXVnRkZTluNlJTRjV4eFVzRkRuM25rZU9tQXphYnpsbjV6WE1WV2JpSkJENW9xUVl6WWNxQzArcXNcL29YTitcL2xHa3RXa1NIMTVUSnc9PSIsIm1hYyI6ImEyZDJiMWQ4MWZiNzkyNWFjMDYwZmY0OGFmNzJjZWY5OTcwY2VlMWEwMThiMGMxMWFlYmU0ZmU4MmM4MDgwYmUifQ
```

After making 1 AJAX request from that page the cookie is reset to:

```
laravel_session = 
 eyJpdiI6IjJITTZlUU9Pc2NTM1Rhd3lweXpHdmh6ZUJzTnZhdlI5WFNTK05pOEhNcFE9IiwidmFsdWUiOiJTcGJ6STN3R2txVnJOQXdKKzFTWGNHSk1Cblk3dkN3bjg0NWVRNmZMbTBJYm9QY3hqcVRSSzg0UlcyYVA3MGFOenR5WHRaNTdpOU54SzNEZTVSMmhwQT09IiwibWFjIjoiNTAwZTE3MGMzZDg5NTRhYWU3YzU1M2YzMWY0YmM4N2I0YzhmMGIyZDE2Y2U2OWNkNDA3NGNmMjBlNjE5MTEzNiJ9
```

This screenshot shows my network tab headers sent when the AJAX request is made:
In the image you can see the AJAX request is setting the new cookie value!

[image]

I need to figure out why the session is reset every AJAX request and how to stop it!

My Routes and Filters only have the basic authentications to require user to be logged in on pages and nothing fancy

A basic AJAX request that causes issue looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/orders/orderboards/order/add-item-comment',
    data: 'order_item_id=' + order_item_id+'&name='+name+'&body='+body+'&user_id='+user_id,
    success: function(result) {
      if(result.success){
        console.log('SUCCESS AJAX Comment created: ');


        working = false;
        $(result.html).hide().insertBefore('#addCommentContainer').slideDown();
        $('#body').val('');

      }else{
        console.log('FAILURE AJAX did not save comment:');
      }

    }
});
```

---

Could it be anything to do with me not posting a form csrf key?

**UPDATE**

I added in CSRF as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/20446415/143030 which adds the token as a header meta tag and then sends it in the AJAX request. I also updated my Filter.php as shown there....

AJAX uses...

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

Header file gets...

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="<?= csrf_token() ?>">
```

Filter gets... 
You also need to modify the CSRF filter to check the ajax request header as well the default Input::get('_token')...

```
Route::filter('csrf', function()
{
   $token = Request::ajax() ? Request::header('X-CSRF-Token') : Input::get('_token');
   if (Session::token() != $token) {
      throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
   }
});
```

Comment: This is how Laravel always behaves -- Laravel encrypts all cookies, and the encrypted value changes every request, but this should not have any negative impact on your sessions. Are you having some sort of problem with your site that makes you think the sessions aren't working properly?

Comment: As Ben said, this is how Laravel and PHP should handle sessions, the session key should be regenerated every request to prevent session hijacking attempts. You problem is most likely caused by something else. Also, didn't you just ask this [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31704786/laravel-4-app-logs-user-out-anytime-an-ajax-post-is-made)?

Comment: Just to add. On Laravel 4 the global csrf functionality is disabled by default, so you don't need to include a token in any of your requests. You might want to provide more information on your environment, was this a problem that only occurred in production? Has it always been occuring? How many Ajax requests are being made, could it be related to [this issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/8172)? What driver are you using for the session?

Comment: What does your method thats called by the ajax request return? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23536877/laravel-4-persisting-data-ongoing-jquery-ajax-submit